# Change polyline options leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to change the options assigned to a Leaflet polyline (and then render it) after building it:

```
// Add polyline
var polyline = L.polyline([], {weight:weight, opacity:1, color:'gray'}).addTo(map);

// Attempts to change color
polyline.options.color = 'blue' // doesn't render
polyline.options.color('blue') // throws error
polyline({color:'blue'}) // throws error
polyline._updateStyle(polyline) // throws error: not sure how exactly this works
polyline._updateStyle() // throws error
polyline({color:blue}) // throws error
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`L.Polyline` is extended from `L.Path` which has a `setStyle` method:

```
polyline.setStyle({
    color: 'black'
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kfLcoG?p=preview

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path